# how to destroy moving object after collision with falling rigidbody body object in unity

Tags: c#, android, unity-game-engine

**SCENERIO**
I have a an sphere with sphere collider and another prefab with rigid body problem is that when i am moving the sphere on touch then sphere donot detroy after the collision with falling rigibody object.Sphere only detory when i donot move the object then it collide with the falling rigidbody object.

**The Code attach with sphere**

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
public class moving : MonoBehaviour {
float speed=100f;
public GameObject hero;
void Start () {
    }
    // Update is called once per frame
void Update () {



            if (Input.touchCount > 0) {

            // The screen has been touched so store the touch
                    Touch touch = Input.GetTouch (0);



                    if (touch.phase == TouchPhase.Stationary || touch.phase == TouchPhase.Moved) {

                            // If the finger is on the screen, move the object smoothly to the touch position
                            Vector3 touchPosition = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint (new Vector3 (touch.position.x, touch.position.y, 100));                
                            transform.position = Vector3.Lerp (transform.position, touchPosition, Time.deltaTime * speed);

                    }

            }

    }

void OnCollisionEnter(Collision coll){

    Debug.Log(coll.gameObject.name);

    if (coll.gameObject.name == "Cube(Clone)") {
        Debug.Log(coll.gameObject.name);
            Destroy (hero); 
    }


}
    }
```

**The Code Attach With Falling rigibody body object**

```
 void Start () {

    InvokeRepeating ("spawn", delay, clone_delay);

}

void spawn () {
    Instantiate (cube, new Vector3 (Random.Range (6, -6), 10, 0), Quaternion.identity);

}
```

Comment: Does collision happen? Do you see the debug message from OnCollisionEnter() when you move the sphere?

Comment: No,when i move the sphere collision does not happen.

Comment: Does your sphere has a rigidbody too? As I know in unity, moving objects with collider is a mistake and should avoided. Instead adding a rigidbody component is suggested. You can check [here](http://forum.unity3d.com/threads/what-exactly-is-considered-moving-static-colliders.159434/)

Comment: Thanks for all suggestions but i got the solution.Actually its my mistake i have a 2d game but i was using OnCollisionEnter() instead of OnCollisionEnter2D().